# Transfer data from one device to another - android

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p, socket-timeout-exception

so I have created two separate apps, one acts as a client & the other acts as a server. Both devices are connected using hotspot:

Connection between the devices is successful. For transferring data from the server to the client, I am using the below code:

```
    public static String downloadDataFromSender(String apiUrl) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        /* Starts the query  */
        conn.connect();
        conn.getResponseCode();

        is = conn.getInputStream();

        /* Convert the InputStream into a string  */
        return readIt(is);
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:343)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:205)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:187)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:113)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:196)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
at com.wifiscanner.utils.DownloadUtils.downloadDataFromSender(DownloadUtils.java:27)
at com.wifiscanner.tasks.SenderAPITask.doInBackground(SenderAPITask.java:29)
at com.wifiscanner.tasks.SenderAPITask.doInBackground(SenderAPITask.java:14)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

The url I am using in the download is this:http://192.168.43.1:52287/files

The connection is successful as I said. So not sure why I am getting network is unreachable. This happens intermittently and not always.

Could someone provide some detail on why this is happening?

Comment: why do you think that `onnection is successful`?

Comment: try opening this url in the web browser of the client device. I think that it won't work for some reason.

Comment: Actually I manually connected to the hotspot created by sender in web browser in pc and it is working. But when it is connected to another device and the device tries to download data from sender I am getting this error